# Trying to add more variables for TimeseriesGenerator (Keras)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am new to Keras and is doing a project about predicting a stock's return by using its past returns and volumes.

My question is, how do I incorporate the past returns and volumes of other stocks as well?

goog[["label"]] here is 1 or 0 indicating positive or negative.

```
val_start_iloc  = goog.index.get_loc(val_start_date,  method = 'bfill') 
test_start_iloc = goog.index.get_loc(test_start_date, method = 'bfill' )

train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(goog[["return", "volume"], goog[["label"]].values,
                                      length = 100, batch_size = 64, end_index = val_start_iloc-1)



search_space = {"lstm_size":     np.linspace(50, 200, 3, dtype = int),
                "dropout":       np.linspace(0, 0.4, 2),
                "learning_rate": np.linspace(0.004, 0.01, 5)}


iterations          = 10
results, best_model = random_search(model_fn, search_space, iterations, "search")
```

I tried adding additional variables (return of intc and fb) by putting them into the goog dataframe like this:

```
train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(goog[["return", "volume"], "intc", "intc_vol", "fb", "fb_vol"]], amzn[["label"]].values,
                                      length = 100, batch_size = 64, end_index = val_start_iloc-1)
```

but later on return the error after running the random search function:

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 100 to array axis with dimension 6